How to Derive a Quadrature Formula Using Cubic Splines?
I am working on a problem involving cubic splines and quadrature formulas. The task requires deriving a specific quadrature formula. Here is the problem setup:
Let
$
s(x) = \sum_{i=-1}^{n+1} \sigma_i B_i(x),
$
where $ B_i(x) $ are the cubic spline basis functions defined over the equidistant partition
$\mathcal{T} = \{ [x_0, x_1], [x_1, x_2], \dots, [x_{n-1}, x_n] \}
 $
with step size $ h $.
We need to derive a quadrature formula of the form:
$
\int_{x_0}^{x_n} s(x) \, dx \approx h \sum_{i=-1}^{n+1} \sigma_i \lambda_i,
$
where $ \lambda_i $ are the weights to be determined.
Task:
Use the composite Simpson's rule to simplify the computation. How can this rule be used directly to determine the weights $ \lambda_i $, without explicitly calculating a quadrature error?
My Attempt:
I expressed $s(x) $ as a linear combination of basis functions:
$\int_{x_0}^{x_n} s(x) \, dx = \sum_{i=-1}^{n+1} \sigma_i \int_{x_0}^{x_n} B_i(x) \, dx.
$
so $ \lambda_i  = \int_{x_0}^{x_n} B_i(x) \, dx $.
However, I am unsure how to distribute the resulting weights $\lambda_i$ among the basis functions, by using the composite Simpson's rule
Any guidance or a step-by-step explanation for deriving the weights $\lambda_i$ systematically would be greatly appreciated!


Note that $x_i = x_0 + ih$ for all $i$ and $B_i(x) = B\left(\frac{x - x_i}h\right)$ where $$B(x) = \begin{cases}\frac14 (x+2)^3&x\in[-2,-1],\-\frac34x^3-\frac32x^2+1&x\in[-1,0],\\frac34x^3-\frac32x^2+1&x\in[0,1],\\frac14(2-x)^3&x\in[1,2],\0&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$ Also note that $B$ is an even function, and it has the same integrals regardless of $i$, except at the ends where the limits $[x_0,x_n]$ don't integrate over all of $B$'s support.

thanks for your answer. now, after I calculated that $B_i\left( \frac{x_\left( i-2 \right)+x_\left( i-1 \right)}{2}  \right)=\frac{1}{32}$ and
$B_i\left( \frac{x_\left( i-1 \right)+x_\left( i \right)}{2}  \right)=\frac{23}{32}$ it was no longer difficult using the composite Simpson's rule. solved it :)
